# Writing image in in directory in opensv code

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write image in my opencv code, which is fine if i write without directory. But when I am trying to write in directory, it run but does not write in directory.

```
for i in xrange(3):
    path = 'resultImages/result'
    print os.path.join(path,str(i),'.png')
    cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path,str(i),'.png'),images[i*3+2])
```

Anything wrong here?

I reffered [OpenCV - Saving images to a particular folder of choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586429/opencv-saving-images-to-a-particular-folder-of-choice) but no help.

Comment: if resultImages is inside the directory where the images are automatically saved, try putting '/' in front of resultImages ('/resultImages/result')

Comment: Make sure you dirpath exists.

Comment: @Silencer: dir path is there, and also tried with `('/resultImages/result')` but no luck

Comment: did you try using the full path? 'D:/..../result'

Comment: try using `os.path.exists(path)` to check if the path exists... also `os.path.join(path,str(i),'.png')` this should give something like `resultImages/result/0/.png` and it should be something like `os.path.join(path,str(i)+'.png')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact you are using `".png"` as a sub directory inside the `os.path.join()` function

Try changing it to this:

```
for i in xrange(3):
    path = 'resultImages/result'
    print os.path.join(path,str(i) + '.png')
    cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path,str(i) +'.png'),images[i*3+2])
```

I hope it helped