# Saving an image to another folder of my choice (with "~") using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am a few images in the "Downloads" folder. I want to save the images to a particular folder named "unclassified" using OpenCV. I have already seen the question [OpenCV - Saving images to a particular folder of choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586429/opencv-saving-images-to-a-particular-folder-of-choice/41587740) and from that I have tried this particular code:

```
 import cv2
 import os
 img = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 1)
 path = '~/Downloads/unclassified'
 cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'waka.jpg'),img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This works on Windows but it didn't work on Ubuntu (I am working on a Ubuntu 16.04) when I wrote:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'waka.jpg'), img)
```

The code returned `False` on Ubuntu. What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(path , 'waka.jpg')), img)
```

The problem is with the "~". [`os.path.expanduser(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) will change that with the appropriate path.