# Save recognized text boxes as files OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, text, image-recognition, text-recognition

I have an image having text, it may be printed or handwritten, in an image format, and I aim to extract each line from it and save each detected box as an individual file in my directory. How can I do it using openCV ?

Input:
[image: original]

Mid processed:
[image: boxed]

Each of the boxes stored as individual image:
[image: final saves]

Answer (score 0):

first crop the image using numpy slicing, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)
and then save to disk using cv2.imwrite function, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586429/opencv-saving-images-to-a-particular-folder-of-choice)

Comment: Would the numpy slicing save all the multiple boxes that are recognised ?